# Why does Android AVD take so long to start up?

Tags: android-emulator

I got the Hello, Android program to work after reading the tutorials from Google's developer website, but it takes SO long for the AVD to load up! Plus, in the console section in the bottom part of Eclipse, two of the lines were written in red, which I'm guessing is bad. It takes around a minute for the AVD to start running the actual program. This is what the console printout looks like:

```
[2010-08-06 12:32:38 - HelloAndroid] ------------------------------
[2010-08-06 12:32:38 - HelloAndroid] Android Launch!
[2010-08-06 12:32:38 - HelloAndroid] adb is running normally.
[2010-08-06 12:32:38 - HelloAndroid] Performing com.example.helloandroid.HelloAndroid activity launch
[2010-08-06 12:32:38 - HelloAndroid] Automatic Target Mode: Preferred AVD 'my_avd' is not available. Launching new emulator.
[2010-08-06 12:32:38 - HelloAndroid] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'my_avd'
[2010-08-06 12:32:54 - HelloAndroid] New emulator found: emulator-5554
[2010-08-06 12:32:54 - HelloAndroid] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
[2010-08-06 12:34:05 - HelloAndroid] WARNING: Application does not specify an API level requirement!
[2010-08-06 12:34:05 - HelloAndroid] Device API version is 8 (Android 2.2)
[2010-08-06 12:34:05 - HelloAndroid] HOME is up on device 'emulator-5554'
[2010-08-06 12:34:05 - HelloAndroid] Uploading HelloAndroid.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2010-08-06 12:34:05 - HelloAndroid] Installing HelloAndroid.apk...
[2010-08-06 12:35:07 - HelloAndroid] Success!
[2010-08-06 12:35:07 - HelloAndroid] Starting activity com.example.helloandroid.HelloAndroid on device 
[2010-08-06 12:35:11 - HelloAndroid] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.example.helloandroid/.HelloAndroid }
```

Now that I looked at the times, I started to run the program at 12:32, and it finally had my program on the screen at 12:35, so thats 3 minutes. Is this a normal amount of time I have to wait? If it isn't, how to make it faster?

Comment: When you created the emulator, did you create an virtual SD card with it?

Comment: I honestly don't know. I just followed the tutorial on android.developer.com, did everything exactly as it said on the Hello Android tutorial, and realized the emulator never started. If the SD card gets created by default, then I guess I did create it, but I didn't see any options about creating a virtual SD card.

Comment: I don't think it's RAM. I've got MacBook Pro 2.53GHz with 4GB RAM and it still takes android emulator 2~3 minutes to launch an app.

Comment: Also, when creating an AVD, check the box that says Snapshot->Enabled. It will speed up future launches.

Comment: It's pretty normal, mine takes 10 minutes, and I love it, I can have a nice time with my family and it's still not ready yet

Comment: 3 minutes? Sounds like a dream. I've just installed Xamarin on Win7 with 16GB and Intel Xeon 3.2GHz 6core. I seriously thought the emulator had 'hung', so I decided to leave it over lunchtime. After an hour it had finally loaded up! I've been playing with all the AVD settings but I can't seem to speed things up. Any ideas?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Well the AVD is a totally different architecture from say a Windows PC.
Windows usually runs on 32bit or 64bit. On Intel or AMD processors.
The Instructions for the processor are written in x86.
The way binary and machine code works/runs is different to each arcitechture.
The android package that you have uploaded onto the device has to be compiled on the AVD architechture. The Emulator has to emaulate ARM architechture so the instruction sent to the CPU is different.
This takes time to compile this code.
Hope this answers it.
Any questions?

Comment: So it's normal for the emulator to take that long? The laptop I have now is a 2 year old Compaq Presario C700, and it only has 1 GB of RAM. Do you think getting a new laptop with 2/4 GB would help? I'm going to get a new one anyway within the next few months, and knowing if having 4 GB instead of 2 will make a difference would definitely help out.

Comment: Well if your application is going to need more than the RAM you have it's best upgrading the RAM.
A good thing would be to find a better laptop with a faster processor.
What Kind of Application are you trying to develop?

Comment: I'm not trying to develop any specific application; I just want to know how to make basic Android apps because I'm going to get a new Android-OS phone really soon (after having the same phone for the last 5 years). I brought up the question about RAM because Eclipse was getting really slow, so when I opened up task manager I found out it was using 180-ish MB. And under the performance tab, it said that out of the 1013 MB of total physical memory, I had 0 free.

Comment: Well that sounds like you need a RAM upgrade. That would be a reason for it taking a while to load. And anyway it is normal for AVD to take its time to load applications.

Comment: Ok, thanks for clearing things up. I'm going to wait until I get a new laptop to have more RAM - I don't want to delay the inevitable. Also, this has Windows Vista, which I can't wait to stop using.

Comment: Hello Pat, have you upgrade the RAM and get the Speed ? I have 4GB RAM but the same problem for me.

Comment: @hysteriax - I am facing the same issue with 4GB ram and 7200RPM HDD. Resource utilization - cpu20%, ram80% due to javaw and Android emulator. I am emulating the ARM. Should I do Intel instead ? How do I make this fast like a real android phone. Its 3 minutes already and I am not even able to see the hello world app in my Big Nerd Ranch Guide book.

Comment: For most of my tests i just use 2 phones, one so older with 4.4 and one newer which has Android 7 and cost me so low. I think that using real phones is way better than wait the emulator :-/ time is gold. For those don't liking the "buy a phone" idea, just try using x86 Android version. Read here: https://doc.nuxeo.com/blog/speeding-up-the-android-emulator/. Anyway, stillway easier to just buy even used phone and install wifi-adb to work with it.

Answer (score 0):

Running Ubuntu 10.10 64bit here. I'm on a AMD phenom 2.5Ghz w/ 8GB memory. for 2.2 bootup time takes 40 seconds, but the OS responds a little sluggish. For 1.5 the bootup only took about 30 seconds and response is snappy.

Also, after you've booted your AVD, hopefully you're all keeping it open and running between run sessions in Eclipse!  You shouldn't be closing it and rebooting the AVD everytime you re-run your app. Just keep the AVD open and Eclipse will reload your app. (take a look at the console output to see when your app has finished reloading)